# "Has been joined"

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

Is it correct to say that a person "has been joined the team"? Is "the user has joined the team" still correct?
This sentence is used as notification on the website.

Comment: "Has been joined" is a verbal phrase that is not "transitive" -- it cannot take an "object".  Hence, "has been joined the team" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: @MετάEd it's funny how your hyperlinks have migrated to ell.stackexchange.com along with my question

Comment: @AlexProutorov The good news is that the site policies are similar. On ELL you are still expected to provide results of research and avoid asking for writing advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The user has joined the team.

is the normal form.

> The user has been joined to the team.

is grammatical but unusual. "Be joined to" usually means "caused to be physically attached to" and would not be used for the metaphorical sense of joining a team.

But I can imagine somebody using "join" in a non-standard transitive (causitive) way, meaning "cause to be come a member", just as people sometimes use "volunteer" in a similar way ("He volunteered me to do the work").

So I can make sense of "The user has been joined to the team" in that way - somebody has made the user join the team; but it is not a standard use of the word.

Without "to" it is not grammatical.

Comment: @AlexProutorov  An idiomatic version of the passive sentence is *The user has been added to the team*.